# does zurb-foundation work with zurb-foundation-apps?

Tags: zurb-foundation

The sass import name is the same between foundation and foundation-apps, they are both foundation.

Is it intended that if you use foundation-apps you would not be using the base foundation styles?

For example, data-alert and notifications from base foundation is not available if you are using foundation-apps even if you include both in your project and import them in your sass.

Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this question has been answered before here: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/21395-zurb-foundation-for-apps-for-websites

Short answers is yes. You'll need to include jQuery and the sites components will work in the new grid. You'll need to watch out for naming issues so you might have to namespace some stuff.